# Merge [threadpool] --> [thread-pool]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

The [threadpool](/questions/tagged/threadpool) tag has 126 questions and [thread-pool](/questions/tagged/thread-pool) tag has 83 questions.

However, I think that [thread-pool](/questions/tagged/thread-pool) tag is more correctly formatted, anyone want to make a synonym for this?

Comment: Unless it's being used as a class name... AFAIK, both Java and .NET have classes named *ThreadPool* or similar.

Comment: @Shog9 That is what was concerning me, because the classname has no space, however if one were talking about the concept of a thread pool, i think [thread-pool] would be more preferable.

Comment: @James: I agree... Unfortunately, it appears that threadpool has been used for both (questions on the class and questions on the concept). Perhaps it *would* be good to merge them all into thread-pool just to avoid confusion, but it'd be nice to see someone else more familiar with the classes weigh in.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a reliable way to distinguish between `[threadpool]` and `[thread-pool]` without context that must be provided in the question itself. `threadpool` as a class/module/library isn't even reliably unique within a given language.

Comment: @Nicholas Knight, then i guess it would make sense to use [thread-pool] if the naming of the threadpool module/class/lib is not consistent.

Comment: One should not forget the class uses a CaseNotion, which the `threadpool` tag does not, but the `thread-pool` tag simulates. Here is another issue: If someone on google searches for "ThreadPool", will it find stackoverflow's `thread-pool`?

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this answer to bring attention to this topic. I wanted to start a new one, but this one is already present, so let's use it.

I also think that the tag [threadpool](/questions/tagged/threadpool) should be merged with [thread-pool](/questions/tagged/thread-pool). Since 2010 the distribution for those two tags has changed. [threadpool](/questions/tagged/threadpool) now has 1383 questions and [thread-pool](/questions/tagged/thread-pool) 103.

Moreover, the description for [thread-pool](/questions/tagged/thread-pool) is `A tag redundant to threadpool` which more or less states that these two are identical.